# SQL copy table column contents to another table column assigned by entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with colums

```
id    toadd
1      0
3      0
4      0
7      0
```

---

```
id    x    y    z
1
3
3
4
5
6
7
```

I need to move the id's from the second table to theyr coresponding id's in the first table. It should result in something like :

```
id    toadd
1      1
3      3
4      4
7      7
```

I tried something like:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (toadd) 
SELECT id FROM table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: try explain better .. seems a simple update .. but .. ???

Comment: It looks like you're just setting `toadd` to be the same as `id`. How is the second table related? Are the x, y, and z columns really supposed to be empty like that?

Comment: I need to move the ids from the second table to the first one on the column "toadd" . They need to be the same. Tryed something like :

Comment: `update table1 set toadd = id`

Comment: You can't use `INSERT` for this. `INSERT` is for creating new rows, you use `UPDATE` to modify existing rows.

Comment: if im doing that command every single id will have a toadd , some might have , some might not, need only the one's from the second table.

Comment: What does that query you tried having to do with the tables in the question? Where are the `id` and `toadd` columns in that query?

Comment: Changed the names so that it would be cleared but the problem stays the same , entry = id , toadd = lootid. Can't seem to find a working solution :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`, to modify existing rows. `INSERT` is only for adding new rows.

To restrict it to just the rows that having matching IDs in the two tables, use a `JOIN`.

```
UPDATE table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
SET t1.toadd = t1.id
```